# how to upload an image for each store view

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Won't let me place images for each product the following message is there...image type and information need to be specified for each store view.
Why does this mean? How do i get my images loaded into each product?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add product image store wise then please select different store from left top corner on the page and save image so you see different image.

[image]

Hope this is help of you.